# Как задавать разный font, чтобы был на одном уровне?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Два вопроса:

1. Нужно использовать разный фонт, использую для этого font-size. В итоге буквы всегда находятся на разных уровнях. Что делать, чтобы выровнять их?
2. Как оформлять font, если его приходится делать разным на одной странице, например, если нужно сделать 5 типов текста с разным size'ом, цветом и жирностью; нужно сделать 5 разных классов?

[image]

Comment: @mr_blond97, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

По умолчанию цвет текста - черный.

Размер текста - 15px.

```
body{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: ...;
}
```

Классы:

```
.color-gray{color:#ccc}
.color-blue(color:#00f)

.font20{font-size:20px} and .f20{font-size:20px}
.font12{font-size:12px} and .f12{font-size:12px}
```

Для жирного текста можно использовать тег `strong`.